# How to run pre-commit in gitlab CI

Tags: python, gitlab, continuous-integration, pre-commit.com

I tried setting up a job as follows in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
precommit:
  image: python:3.10.2-slim-bullseye
  before_script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - pre-commit run --all-files
```

But the following error is output :

```
$ pre-commit run --all-files
An error has occurred: FatalError: git failed. Is it installed, and are you in a Git repository directory?
```

I checked that there was a `.git` where the command was being used from - and there is - so I'm not sure why this particular error is being flagged, or how to fix it.

Comment: read the error message again

Answer (score 4):

The `python:3.10` image does not include `git` which is needed by pre-commit.

Install git to resolve the issue:

```yaml
precommit:
  image: python:3.10.2-slim-bullseye
  before_script:
    - apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends git
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
  # ...
```

---

As a side note, maybe also consider taking a look at [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab/articles/71270196/how-to-use-pre-commit-to-automatically-correct-commits-and-merge-requests-with-g) explaining use of pre-commit in gitlab and the additional references contained therein.

Answer (score 0):

Arriving here after having the same error. The problem is likely the mismatch between the git repository owner and the user in the CI image, which causes git to fail with

```bash
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '<CI_PROJECT_DIR>'
To add an exception for this directory, call:
    git config --global --add safe.directory '<CI_PROJECT_DIR>'
```

therefore this is easily fixed by executing

```bash
git config --global --add safe.directory $CI_PROJECT_DIR
```

before running pre-commit.